# Migrate CentOS 8 to AlmaLinux (cannot install both <package-name>)

Tags: linux, migration, centos8

Due to Centos is about EOL. I decided to migrate to AlmaLinux. I started the migration process but I got some errors.

```
[root@19827364 ~]# dnf distro-sync -y
Last metadata expiration check: 4:35:36 ago on Thu 23 Sep 2021 06:29:49 PM +03.
Error:
 Problem 1: package libdb-devel-5.3.28-42.el8_4.x86_64 requires libdb(x86-64) = 5.3.28-42.el8_4, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both libdb-5.3.28-40.el8.x86_64 and libdb-5.3.28-42.el8_4.x86_64
  - cannot install both libdb-5.3.28-42.el8_4.x86_64 and libdb-5.3.28-40.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libdb-devel-5.3.28-42.el8_4.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libdb-5.3.28-42.el8_4.x86_64
 Problem 2: package libstdc++-devel-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64 requires libstdc++(x86-64) = 8.4.1-1.el8.alma, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both libstdc++-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64 and libstdc++-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - cannot install both libstdc++-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64 and libstdc++-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libstdc++-devel-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libstdc++-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
 Problem 3: libgcc-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.i686 has inferior architecture
  - package gcc-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64 requires libgcc >= 8.4.1-1.el8.alma, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both libgcc-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64 and libgcc-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - cannot install both libgcc-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64 and libgcc-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libgcc-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package gcc-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
 Problem 4: problem with installed package gcc-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - package gcc-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64 requires libgomp = 8.4.1-1.el8.alma, but none of the providers can be installed
  - libgomp-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.i686 has inferior architecture
  - package gcc-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64 requires cpp = 8.4.1-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package gcc-8.2.1-3.5.el8.x86_64 requires cpp = 8.2.1-3.5.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both libgomp-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64 and libgomp-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - cannot install both libgomp-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64 and libgomp-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install both cpp-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64 and cpp-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - cannot install both cpp-8.2.1-3.5.el8.x86_64 and cpp-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libgomp-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package cpp-8.4.1-1.el8.alma.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I know that it's not possible to install two packages at the same time. So, I tried to remove the old one but it says that I'm trying to remove a private package (sudo) !!

I tried to downgrade/upgrade each package of the mentioned packages in the errors above but nothing changed! Then I googled for that issue but it seems that there's no further information about this issue.

Anyone can help please?
Thanks.

Comment: You should follow each of the three suggestions that it gave you, one at a time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I tried but as I mentioned before, this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You should add the output to your question, then.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I already added it sir. I tried to upgrade/remove/downgrade the mentioned packages then I run the command above then I get the same outputs.

Comment: No, you did not. You were advised to try all three suggestions given to you above: `(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)`. There is no output corresponding to any of these three in your question.

Comment: These also hasn't solve the issue. They skip the conflicts only.

Comment: You still need to add the output to your question.